# SQL statement ignored while doing arithmetic

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying some arithmetic in PL/SQL. However, I am having a problem in the arithmetic while adding,multiplying,etc two elements of an array.

My arrays are Efficiency,Salary,Cash. All are of four elements each. I have the following problem. Whenever I am dividing the two elements in the following manner,

```
EFFICIENCY(2):=SALARIES(2)/CASH(2);
```

I get an `SQL statement ignored error`. Why does this happen?

P.S: I am dividing the elements in a loop, i.e, `EFFICIENCY(I):=SALARIES(I)/CASH(I);`

I am posting the whole source code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ANALYSIS
IS
CURSOR EMPLOYEES IS
 SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
CURSOR BILLS IS
 SELECT * FROM BILL;
WORKER EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPE;
CASH BILL%ROWTYPE;
TYPE SALARY IS VARRAY(4) OF NUMBER(6,2);
SALARIES SALARY:=SALARY(0,0,0,0);
AMOUNTS SALARY:=SALARY(0,0,0,0);
EFFICIENCY SALARY:=SALARY(0,0,0,0);

BEGIN 

 OPEN EMPLOYEES;
 OPEN BILLS;
 LOOP
  FETCH EMPLOYEES INTO WORKER;
  EXIT WHEN EMPLOYEES%NOTFOUND;
  IF WORKER.BRANCHID=1 THEN 
   SALARIES(1):=SALARIES(1)+WORKER.SALARY;
  ELSIF WORKER.BRANCHID=2 THEN 
   SALARIES(2):=SALARIES(2)+WORKER.SALARY;
  ELSIF WORKER.BRANCHID=3 THEN 
   SALARIES(3):=SALARIES(3)+WORKER.SALARY;
  ELSIF WORKER.BRANCHID=4 THEN 
   SALARIES(4):=SALARIES(4)+WORKER.SALARY;
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
 LOOP
  FETCH BILLS INTO CASH;
  EXIT WHEN BILLS%NOTFOUND;
  IF CASH.BRANCHID=1 THEN
   AMOUNTS(1):=AMOUNTS(1)+CASH.AMOUNT;
  ELSIF CASH.BRANCHID=2 THEN
   AMOUNTS(2):=AMOUNTS(2)+CASH.AMOUNT;
  ELSIF CASH.BRANCHID=3 THEN
   AMOUNTS(3):=AMOUNTS(3)+CASH.AMOUNT;
  ELSIF CASH.BRANCHID=4 THEN
   AMOUNTS(4):=AMOUNTS(4)+CASH.AMOUNT;
  END IF;
 END LOOP;

 FOR I IN 1..4 LOOP
  EFFICIENCY(I):=SALARIES(I)/CASH(I);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I);
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Can you please post a simple, complete example of the code you run that gives the error?

Comment: Okay, I will. But my coding isn't that good, so I avoided posting it. I'll edit and post it.

Comment: 'SQL statement ignored' is usually only one of several related error messages, and the preceding ones will say what is actually wrong; so can you add the whole error stack to the question, as well as the code?

Comment: The error stack is only that much. Nothing more. In fact, if I remove the arithmetic statement, my code compiles perfectly.

Comment: Instead of `IF ... ELSIF` simply use `SALARIES(WORKER.BRANCHID):=SALARIES(WORKER.BRANCHID)+WORKER.SALARY;` for instance

Comment: @Wernfried I would, but it gives me something called a bind error. That was going to be my next question. How do I resolve this bind error?

Comment: @Wernfried I tried with a colon `:` and without one. If I use a colon before the name, I get a bind error and if I use it without, then I get the error `expression is of wrong type.`

Comment: The branchid is an integer. It gives me an error of wrong type if I use it without a colon. And if I use a colon, it gives me the error that there is a bad binding.

Comment: @RohitShinde - the code Wernfried suggested is fine; I've answered your next question which shows the 'wrong type' and bind errors are nothing to do with this approach. How are you running these - what client are you using, and are you seeing the errors when you try to create the procedures, or when you try to execute them? If the latter exactly how are you calling them? I don't understand why you don't get the full error stack...

Comment: I am surprised myself. Not getting the full error stack is seriously hampering my ability to weed out errors. I use oracle 11g. The Application Express version. Does this have anything to do with me not getting the full error stack?

Comment: @RohitShinde - do you mean 11g Express Edition; or are you using APEX as the client to run this, rather than something like SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, Toad etc.? (SQL Workshop? I don't use APEX...)

Comment: @RohitShinde - wow, yes, I had no idea APEX's SQL Workshop gave you so little information for errors. If you can I'd suggest you connect to your database using a different client, like [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, I have Oracle 11g and I use the Application Express Client. The thing is, I have a DBMS course this semester in college. And we were just told to install 11g, I have absolutely no idea about other clients. However, I will  install one of those you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be seeing a `PLS-00222: no function with name 'CASH' exists in this scope` error.

`CASH` is defined as `BILL%ROWTYPE`, not as an array, so you can't refer to `CASH(I)` in your arithmetic. I'm not sure what you're intending that do to, so it isn't clear how it should be modified, but from the population I think you meant to refer to `AMOUNTS` there:

```
EFFICIENCY(2):=SALARIES(2)/AMOUNTS(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using CASH as if it were an array here:

```
EFFICIENCY(I):=SALARIES(I)/CASH(I);
```

But it isn't an array:

```
CASH BILL%ROWTYPE;
```

So you get:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
43/3     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
43/30    PLS-00222: no function with name 'CASH' exists in this scope
```

I don't know why you are only seeing the first error message?

Comment: Even I don't know. It only said SQL statement ignored. I am using Oracle 11g. Maybe its got something to do with that.